# What are the options for data warehousing in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-platform, data-warehouse

I've set up a test app in GCP with a Google Cloud MySQL db. I then want to create a DWH to extract some of the data from the MySQL db and then analyze further on it. We're talking about 40.000 rows pr. month, so the amount of data is "small". After googling for some time, the most frequent option that occurs is BigQuery, but after reading about BigQuery it seems like overkill, since it's designed for vast amounts of data.

What are the GCP native options for building a DWH layer and possible a semantic layer on top similar to Azure's Data Factory, Azure SQL og Azure Anaysis Services?

Comment: I think it boils down to the the type of analytics you want to achieve ...  what will you actually be doing with the data that you warehouse?  If visualization or reporting then maybe DataStudio or Looker which can source from a variety of databases.  As for BQ, it is indeed Google's primary DW product.  While it can process peta bytes of data it should be just as happy processing only giga bytes.

Comment: Why do you not perform the processing directly into MySQL if the volume of data is low? What are you looking for as additional feature?

Comment: Along the same lines as guillaume recommends here, I'd say just stick with Cloud SQL, but perhaps setup a read replica to run the analytics on, depending on how "intense" the analytics get it might have some small impact on the production server so might be valid to setup a replica for analytics.

Comment: @Kolban The analytics are going to be rather lightweight, and I'm thinking on using a front-end tool like Power BI to visualize the data. However, I'm was more curios about the "ETL" part of the Google Stack, ie. how do you prepare and reshape your data in GCP.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm looking for a ressource that allows me to do the classic ETL type of stuff to my data, and probably add a semantic model on top of that like you'd do with MS Analysis Services.

Comment: @GabeWeiss Yes, I was thinking that it could make sense to make a replica of the prod. db, but I'm more curios about the options for passing the data between MySQL and some sort of ETL tool

Comment: @Artem It really depends. There's nothing really out of the box to do the ETL, but there's tools like Dataflow or Dataproc (hosted Apache Beam and Spark respectively). Or you could also have a scheduled Cloud Task which triggers a Cloud Function, or a service/container running in Cloud Run to do the transformation and move the reshaped/transformed data somewhere else for the visualization.

Comment: @GabeWeiss So I just stumbled upon this: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/designing-etl-architecture-for-a-cloud-native-data-warehouse-on-google-cloud-platform

Guess it's an example of what I'm looking for, and what you're suggesting.

Comment: What kind of operation do you want to perform on your data? Do you need to call external API? Do you need to perform machine learning prediction on these data? Do you need to write SQL or Javascript script to transform your data?

Comment: @Artem Oh cool! Didn't know someone blogged on it (but not surprised). Sergei is one of the PMs on Dataflow (managed Apache Beam).

Comment: @GabeWeiss Took me too long to find - thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer to this question so that other community memmebrs can use it? Thanks.

Comment: @Katayoon will do so, when I'm done testing my solution.